# if setView in map is not called it doesn't display map?

Tags: leaflet

Following first code snippet doesn't display map

Snippet 1:

```
var mapEle = document.getElementById('map');        
var map = L.map(mapEle);
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/map/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
          attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright" title="OpenStreetMap" target="_blank">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors | Tiles Courtesy of <a href="http://www.mapquest.com/" title="MapQuest" target="_blank">MapQuest</a> <img src="http://developer.mapquest.com/content/osm/mq_logo.png" width="16" height="16">',
          subdomains: ['otile1','otile2','otile3','otile4']     
        }).addTo(map);
```

Snippet 2:

```
var mapEle = document.getElementById('map');        
var map = L.map(mapEle).setView([43.07265,-89.400929], 10);
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/map/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
          attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright" title="OpenStreetMap" target="_blank">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors | Tiles Courtesy of <a href="http://www.mapquest.com/" title="MapQuest" target="_blank">MapQuest</a> <img src="http://developer.mapquest.com/content/osm/mq_logo.png" width="16" height="16">',
          subdomains: ['otile1','otile2','otile3','otile4']     
        }).addTo(map);
```

Made change in second line of first snippet, Added  `setView([43.07265,-89.400929], 10)`, it displays map, am i missing something, or setview is compulsory?

**UPDATE**

`leaflet version: 0.7.3`

Comment: Yes, setView() is compulsory. Same case happens with me. Then I google and come to know that setView() is compulsory. Otherwise map doesn't load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with setView(), you tell leaflet which tile(s) http://{s}.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/map/{z}/{x}/{y}.png must be fetched from the server.

So yes it is compulsory